# How do I select a variable by its name using 'exec'

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

I have an issue I am struggling to fix. I need to make an input that will allow the user to name a variable, but how would I then use this variable?

To make it I just have to do:

```
a = input('var name?')
exec(a)
```

So if the user enters 'dog' that will be a variable called `dog`, but how do I then use this variable? I don't have its name so is it even possible?

Additionally, how do I make it a global variable if it's in a function? Sorry about my bad grammar and English. I am not really sure what to try.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: What if I want my variable to be `import shutil; shutil.rmtree('/')`?

Comment: What does `exec` have to do with the creation of the variable?

Comment: @Tagc You would have what you asked for.

Comment: You want `exec('{} = 0'.format(a))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you *can* do this, but I'm not sure why you would. Whatever you do, **don't use** `exec` for the reasons brought up by Tagc in the comments.

```
>>> a = input('var name? ')
var name? dog
>>> globals()[a] = 'hi everyone'
>>> dog
'hi everyone'
```

And you *do* have the name, it's in `a`, and you can access it in `globals()`:

```
>>> globals()[a]
'hi everyone'
>>>
```

But this just brings the point home: why not just use a `dict` instead of the `globals()` `dict`?

Comment: i tried dict but it was causing issues with some of the modules i was using, thank you for this, it was very helpful.